# How to rewrite wordpress category url

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, web

A have a wordpress theme, which has a built-in services module. All items in that can be found at *domain.com/services/item*. I rewrote a php file so links to these service items look like *domain.com/something-else/item*, but they point to the 404 page.

I would like to modify my site's **.htaccess** file to display the original *domain.com/services/item* content while users see *domain.com/something-else/item*.

I would like to use the url (something-else) instead the other(services) one, while keeping content the same.

Ha can I achieve this using .htaccess?

Comment: can't you just change the category slug in the admin panel?

Comment: no this is not exactly a category, it is a module

Answer (score 0):

Just use the buit-in Rewrite API of wordpress :

http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API

Example : http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/wordpress-url-rewrite/